# Что делать если у элемента нет поддержки команд?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Мне нужно задать картинке (Image) команду, но она не поддерживается на этом элементе. Как поступить в такой ситуации?

Comment: что значит `задать картинке (Image) команду` ?

Comment: Наверное нужен InputBindings, где транслировать события в команды.

Comment: Имхо, лучше всего использовать кнопку с измененным шаблоном вместо картинки. Так же можно попробовать InputBindings и System.Windows.Interactivity.

Comment: Мне помог InputBindings, спасибо

Comment: смотря какую команду тебе нужно. Если это какой то слайдер, то картинки хранятся в какой то переменной, можно в свойствах эксессоров(get, set) смотреть, какие картинки приходят и производить с ними работы. аналогично, с изменением размера картинки, просто сделать Binding на Width и Height